# Why am I getting this error?

Tags: javascript

```
function changeSize( fontsize ) {

    var body = document.getElementById("body");
        var font = fontsize + "-font";
        body.className = font;

}


<input type="button" onclick="changeSize(small)" value="Small" />
```

Firefox console keeps saying that small is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing in `small` as a variable, not a string to put into the DOM. Javascript is looking for the `var small` to be defined somewhere, and it's not. You need to pass in a string as an argument.

Try `onclick="changeSize('small')"`

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a variable named small to the function changeSize(), and Firefox is saying you have not defined a variable by that name yet. Though I suspect you really mean to pass the string "small".  Put single quotes around it and you should be good.

```
<input type="button" onClick="changeSize('small')" value="Small" />
```